# How to change submit button to update button

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview, postback

I guys i have two page On fist page i have my form and on second is report page where my form values store in grid. i have submit button on my form page now when i click on edit link i will redirect to my form page where i can make change and update details. now what i want is when i click on edit link and move to my form page to make editing my submit button change to update button how can i do that...

here is my code for first page:

Select
           TRAVELONG
           ONETRAVEL
           .UK-BSP
           .CA-YYZ
           .CA-YVR
           Partial MCO Refund

```
<div id="FirstForm" style="margin-left: 80px" runat="server">
<table class="style1">
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="lblTid" runat="server" Text="TID"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbTid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTid" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbTid" ErrorMessage="Enter Tid" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblUnusedTicketAmount" runat="server" 
                   Text="Unused Ticket Amount"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbUnusedTicketAmount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUnusedTicketAmount" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbUnusedTicketAmount" ErrorMessage="Enter Amount" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUnusedAmount" runat="server">
                   <asp:ListItem>USD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>CAD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>GBP</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style14">
               <asp:Label ID="lblPNR" runat="server" Text="PNR"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style9">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbPNR" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style8">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPNR" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbPNR" ErrorMessage="Enter PNR" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style9">
               <asp:Label ID="lblAirlinePenality" runat="server" Text="Airline Penality"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style12">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbAirlinePenality" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style10">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAirlinePenality" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbAirlinePenality" ErrorMessage="Enter Penality" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style10">
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAirlinePenality" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                   <asp:ListItem>USD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>CAD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>GBP</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="lblTicketNumber" runat="server" Text="Ticket Number"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbTicketNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTicketNumber" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbTicketNumber" ErrorMessage="Enter ESAC" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblNetRefundProcess" runat="server" Text="Net Refund Process"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbNetRefundProcess" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNetRefundProcess" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbNetRefundProcess" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNetRefundProcess" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                   <asp:ListItem>USD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>CAD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>GBP</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="lblESACCode" runat="server" Text="ESAC Code"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbESACCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvESACCode" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbESACCode" ErrorMessage="Enter ESAC code" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblRefundableCommision" runat="server" 
                   Text="Refundable Commission"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbRefundableCommision" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRefundableCommission" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbRefundableCommision" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRefundableCommission" runat="server" 
                   AutoPostBack="True">
                   <asp:ListItem>USD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>CAD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>GBP</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="lblWaiverCode" runat="server" Text="Waiver Code"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbWaiverCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvWaiverCode" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbWaiverCode" ErrorMessage="Enter Waiver Code" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblCouponRefunded" runat="server" Text="Coupon Refunded"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbCouponRefund" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCouponRefunded" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbCouponRefund" ErrorMessage="Enter Coupon Refund" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Remarks"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbRemarks" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRemarks" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbRemarks" ErrorMessage="Enter Remarks" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblRefundType" runat="server" Text="Refund Type"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRefundType" runat="server">
                   <asp:ListItem>Full</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>Partial</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRefundType" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="ddlRefundType" ErrorMessage="Select Refund Type" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13" colspan="7">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit"/>
               <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" onclick="btnReset_Click" Text="Reset"/>                
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

aspx.cs page code:

```
    protected void  btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Bart;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    string Portal = ddlPortal.SelectedValue;
    string TID = tbTid.Text;
    string PNR = tbPNR.Text;
    string TicketNumber = tbTicketNumber.Text;
    string ESACCode = tbESACCode.Text;
    string WaiverCode = tbWaiverCode.Text;
    string Remarks = tbRemarks.Text;
    string UnusedTicketAmount = tbUnusedTicketAmount.Text;
    string UnusedAmount = ddlUnusedAmount.SelectedValue;
    string AirlinePenality = tbAirlinePenality.Text;
    string Airline = ddlAirlinePenality.SelectedValue;
    string NetRefundProcess = tbNetRefundProcess.Text;
    string NetRefund = ddlNetRefundProcess.SelectedValue;
    string RefundableCommission = tbRefundableCommision.Text;
    string Refundable = ddlRefundableCommission.SelectedValue;
    string CouponRefunded = tbCouponRefund.Text;
    string RefundType = ddlRefundType.SelectedValue;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Form3(Portal,TID,PNR,TicketNumber,ESACCode,WaiverCode,Remarks,UnusedTicketAmount,ddlUnusedAmount, AirlinePenality, ddlAirlinePenality, NetRefundProcess, ddlNetRefundProcess, RefundableCommission, ddlRefundableCommission, CouponRefunded,RefundType) values('" + Portal + "','" + TID + "','" + PNR + "','" + TicketNumber + "', '" + ESACCode + "', '" + WaiverCode + "', '" + Remarks + "','" + UnusedTicketAmount + "','" + UnusedAmount + "','" + AirlinePenality + "','" + Airline + "','" + NetRefundProcess + "','" + NetRefund + "','" + RefundableCommission + "','" + Refundable + "','" + CouponRefunded + "','" + RefundType + "')";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Portal", ddlPortal.SelectedIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TID", tbTid.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNR", tbPNR.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TicketNumber", tbTicketNumber.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ESACCode", tbESACCode.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WaiverCode", tbWaiverCode.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", tbRemarks.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnusedTicketAmount", tbUnusedTicketAmount.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddlUnusedAmount", ddlUnusedAmount.SelectedIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AirlinePenality", tbAirlinePenality.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddlAirlinePenality", ddlAirlinePenality.SelectedIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetRefundProcess", tbNetRefundProcess.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddlNetRefundProcess", ddlNetRefundProcess.SelectedIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefundableCommission", tbRefundableCommision.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddlRefundableCommission", ddlRefundableCommission.SelectedIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CouponRefunded", tbCouponRefund.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefundType", ddlRefundType.SelectedIndex);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
    tbTid.Text = "";
    tbPNR.Text = "";
    tbTicketNumber.Text = "";
    tbESACCode.Text = "";
    tbWaiverCode.Text = "";
    tbRemarks.Text = "";
    tbRemarks.Text = "";
    tbUnusedTicketAmount.Text = "";
    tbAirlinePenality.Text = "";
    tbNetRefundProcess.Text = "";
    tbRefundableCommision.Text = "";
    tbCouponRefund.Text = "";
    lblRefundType.Text = "";
    tbTid.Focus();
}
```

Second report page::

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand1">
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Query">
            <itemtemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton CommandName="cmdBind"  runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("ID")%>' ID="ID" ToolTip='<%#Eval("ID")%>'>LinkButton
            </asp:LinkButton>                                                                   
            </itemtemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>            
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Portal" HeaderText="Portal" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TID" HeaderText="TID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PNR" HeaderText="PNR" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNumber" HeaderText="Ticket Number" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ESACCode" HeaderText="ESACCode" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="WaiverCode" HeaderText="WaiverCode" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnusedTicketAmount" HeaderText="UnusedTicketAmount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlUnusedAmount" HeaderText="ddlUnusedAmoun" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AirlinePenality" HeaderText="AirlinePenality" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlAirlinePenality" HeaderText="ddlAirlinePenality" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NetRefundProcess" HeaderText="NetRefundProcess" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlNetRefundProcess" HeaderText="ddlNetRefundProcess" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RefundableCommission" HeaderText="RefundableCommission" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlRefundableCommission" HeaderText="ddlRefundableCommission" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CouponRefunded" HeaderText="CouponRefunded" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RefundType" HeaderText="RefundType" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
    </Columns>       
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs page of report:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Form3", con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt.Clear();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }

}
protected void GridView1_RowCommand1(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "cmdBind")
    {
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;

        Response.Redirect("Form.aspx?ID=" + lb.Text + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: can u mention the ID of the control you want to change?

Comment: no i didn't can you tell me how to do that

Comment: do u want to change the text of control with ID btnSubmit???

Comment: yes i want to change the text as well we i want to update the value that i change on my form page

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `State Management` technique to implement this. I have used `Session` to demonstrate.

On your page where you have the `Submit` button you need to create a `property` like this:

```
public string ButtonTextValue  
{
    get 
    {
        if (Session["ButtonValue"] == null)
            Session["ButtonValue"] = "Submit";

            return Convert.ToString(Session["ButtonValue"]); 
    }
    set
    {
            Session["ButtonValue"] = value;
    }
}
```

On `pageload` of the same page you need to do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        YourButton.Text = ButtonTextValue;
    }
}
```

And on the second page you need to do this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "cmdBind")
    {
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
        Session["ButtonValue"] = "Update";
        Response.Redirect("Form.aspx?ID=" + lb.Text + "");              
    }
}
```